# Experience Editor is not loading theme style sheets

Tags: sxa, experience-editor

Application is running Sitecore v9 Update 1 with SXA v1.6. I have cloned a site and I have added a new language to this site. I'm trying to edit a page in Experience Editor in new language version but, apparently, style sheets are not loading:

[image: SXA Experience Editor]

Any idea on what would be happening and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this issue? What detail can you give? Have you checked log files for errors? If you view the source, can you see the CSS files being referenced? There are so many things that could be going wrong, SSE is not a place to debug, we need more detail to try and give you an answer.

Comment: Did you change the theme?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I try to add additional information:
- Site: "de"
- Language: "German"
- Home:
    - Page Design: "Default"
- "Default" design:
    - Selected: Header, Empty, Metadata, Footer
    - Page Design Theme: Standard

In frontend the only stylesheet neing rendered is Bootstrap minified:
 
`<link href="/de/-/media/Feature/Experience-Accelerator/Bootstrap/Bootstrap/Styles/optimized-min.css?t=20191114T154106Z" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: In addition I'm trying to not to minify and concatenate assets and it is not working. I have set options as described in official documentation both globally and site specific: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/enable-and-configure-the-asset-optimizer.html

Comment: Perhaps screenshots of what you changed would reveal the issue. I suspect your modifications to the the resulted in other base themes not loading.